# A question on Cauchy sub-sequences in a metric space $(X,d)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, and let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $X$. Prove that if $(x_n)$ has a Cauchy subsequence, then for any decreasing sequence of positive $\epsilon_k \rightarrow 0$, there is a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ of $(x_n)$ such that 
$$ d(x_{n_k},x_{n_l})\leq \epsilon_k \hspace{5mm} \text{for all } k\leq l.$$

Comment: Note that the problem really just boils down to this one: if $\sigma=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a Cauchy sequence in $X$, and $\langle\epsilon_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a sequence of positive reals converging to $0$, then $\sigma$ has a subsequence $\langle x_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ such that $d(x_{n_k},x_{n_\ell})\le\epsilon_k$ whenever $k\le\ell$. In other words, you might as well get rid of one layer of subscripts by starting with a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: If $(x_n)$ has a Cauchy subsequence then the sequence $(x_n)$ is Cauchy?

Comment: @RDev: No, not necessarily.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what the question was asking. It's asking to find a subsequence of the cauchy subsequence such that $d(x_{n_k},x_{n_l}) \leq \epsilon_k   \text{ for all } k\leq l$ and you defined $\sigma$ as the cauchy subsequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Brian is saying is that you are given that a sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ has a Cauchy subsequence, which means that there are $n_1, n_2, ...$ such that $(x_{n_k})_{k=1}^\infty$ is a Cauchy sequence, so by relabeling, we can just assume that $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is your Cauchy sequence.

So given the sequence of $(\varepsilon_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ we know there is an $N_1$ for $\varepsilon_1$ such that if $m>n \geq N_1$ then $d(x_m, x_n) < \varepsilon_1$.  Similarly, there is an $N_2$ for $\varepsilon_2$ such that if $m>n \geq N_2$ then $d(x_m, x_n) < \varepsilon_2$.  Inductively, we have an $N_k$ for $\varepsilon_k$ such that if $m>n \geq N_k$ then $d(x_m, x_n) < \varepsilon_k$.

So then our subsequence is $(x_{N_k})_{k=1}^\infty$ and then we have that $d(x_{N_k}, x_{N_l}) < \varepsilon_k$ for $l \geq k$. (Here if $l > k$ then $l$ corresponds to the $m$ above and $k$ corresponds to $n$, if $l = k$ then $d(x_{N_k}, x_{N_l}) = 0$.)